# 24 inch 4:3 (Non Widescreen) Monitors

Tags: display, hardware-rec

Is there any monitor that fits this requirement?

I'm looking for nothing smaller than 22" though.

Comment: 4:3 is not square! And the great thing about wide-screen is that people often have grater field of vision to the sides than up and down. This way you can with less eye movement see larger part of the screen. Also, take a look here http://superuser.com/questions/46530/ This question is a bit different than the one I pointed, since you need >22".

Comment: Widescreen monitors also follow the current tv/video standards, so you can watch more movies without bits chopped off the side or black bars.

Comment: 4:3 is commonly (although geometrically incorrectly refered to as "square" in order to distinguish  - or avoid the use of - non-widescreen. I don't mind it at all. Unless you are watching movies or the widescreen monitor is a 27 inches or larger, I'll take a "square" 19" or more any day of the week! Finding it is another story unfortunately

Comment: You might consider rotating a widescreen monitor so that it is taller than it is wide.  I know many people that do this in order to reduce scrolling.

Comment: Would rotating a widescreen monitor actually work? The idea that the monitor would decide to flip upon itself is somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: (I know 4:3 nis not square, just it's easier to say than more square than a rectangle but not perfectly square :) )I actuall have a 24" which rotates vertically, the problem with this though, is that the pixels are then not in their correct orientation, which causes problems as we have 2 eyes, so one eye sees a slightly darker version than the other, which is not pleasant. Even with a widescreen I often find I have black bars, but If I had a 24" 4:3 screen then the bars wouldn't matter as they'd be so big.

Comment: I often want to want a video on one side, and have a document or code open on the other, but video can only be done on half a horizontal screen, but documents suit vertical screens. Also a widescreen is great for having 2 documents side by side until you realise it would be greater if you could see the whole of both documents at the same time. I would imagine that this type of 24" 4:3 would be useful in areas, like 3D modelling (though I guess for that you can have multiple monitors), web design, and writting code(especially where the code is wide and long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 21.3" is close enough to 22" for you :), then there is the ColorEdge CG211, FlexScanL997 and FlexScan S2100 from eizo 
http://www.eizo.com/global/iblick/productfinder/#s=s;12=4;14=2;h=1

Comment: is there a technical limitation that 21.3" is the max?

Comment: I believe that although there are mathematical :) reasons for having distinct steps in the sizes of monitors (so that you don't end up with "wierd" resolution values), the fact that there seems to be nothing larger that 21.3 in the 4:5 aspet ratio is more of a supply/demand/market-trend type of phenomenon :)